# Get anchor and all params in request path

Tags: django, request

For a development with django, I try to get the parameters of my url.
my path :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/candy#bubblizz
candy is my view avec #bubblizz is my id anchor.

A lot of documentation on request items but impossible to find how to get the anchor

```
{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}   => http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/candy
{{ request.get_full_path }}        => /categories/candy
{{ request.path }}                 => /categories/candy
{{ request.META.PATH_INFO}}        => /categories/candy
```

The goal is to test the presence of the anchor in the url.

```
{% if bubblizz in request.anchor %}Yeah{% endif %}
```

Does anyone have an idea? Or documentation that might help?

Thanks

Comment: The *fragment* (anchor) is never send to the server, so Django can not know the fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after the hash is called the [*fragment* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment), these are not send to the server, as is specified in the Wikipedia article:

> Clients are **not supposed to send URI fragments** to servers when they retrieve a document, and without help from a local application (see below) fragments do not participate in HTTP redirections.

Django thus never is given the `#bubblizz` part of the URI. You will need to work with some JavaScript to detect the fragment, and for example make an AJAX query and update the DOM accordingly. You can do this with [`window.location.hash` <sup>[mdn]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash) to get the fragment for the URI of the window.